# How to synchronize mail on the server and in my application using IMAP(MailKit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, imap, mailkit

I write my mail client using the MailKit library. The problem arose like this: I cache messages in the local database, for performance. How can I then synchronize the cache in the database and the data on the server at the next login. Maybe the messages have some kind of flag, well, for example, all changes in messages from such and such a date.

I tried to find information about CONDSTORE and QRESYNC. but got confused and didn't find concrete examples. There, it seems that you can subscribe to the folder change event, but it turns out that if the server falls or is stopped, then the next time you turn it on, there will be no synchronization. And I need to press the synchronization button and everything is synchronized as quickly as possible

Comment: Did you read the readme from MailKit project? There is an example how to exclude messages you already had fetched

Comment: Can you link to an example please?

Comment: The github page from the MailKit project? Well, yes https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#fetching-information-about-the-messages-in-an-imap-folder

Comment: The most basic way is to store the UID of the newest message you have. Then synchronize all flags, and download messages with new UIDs, and delete any messages that no longer exist (eg UID SEARCH ALL)  A fundamental tenet of the IMAP is messages do not change after they’re in the mailbox, only their flags. CONDSTORE and QRESYNC, if they’re even available, are just optimizations to that basic algorithm. They help reduce synchronization traffic on large folders, but are not always supported so you need the basic algorithm first.